# Pushforward of domain v.s. pullback of form

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

If we have a map $f: X \to Y$ and $\omega$ is a differential form on $Y$ with same dimension as $X$.  When can we have the following identity,
$$\int_X f^*\omega=\int_{f(X)}\omega$$
I only know that when $f$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism onto its image, this is true. Are there any other wider cases for this to hold?

Also, when can we have it's valid on topological level (under the assumption that $\omega$ and $X$ are both closed,  that is
$$\langle f^*[\omega],[X]\rangle = \langle [\omega],f_*[X]\rangle$$

Comment: What is your definition of $\int_{f(X)}\omega$? As for the "homological form," yes, this is true once you unravel the definitions.

Comment: @MoisheKohan sorry I thought the definition was clear. I think the case is only interesting when the dimension of $f(X)$ and $\omega$ agree, in this case the integration is well-defined.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Also, could you explain a bit why the homological setting is ture or could you please point me to some reference? Thank you so much!

Comment: If you think it is clear, state the definition or give a reference. For instance, it does not appear that you assume that $X$ and $Y$ are oriented, that $X$ is compact, or that $\omega$ has compact support and the same degree as the common dimension of $X$ and $Y$ or that $f$ is a proper map. Without all these assumptions, I do not know  how to make sense of the integrals that you wrote. I also do not know what the word "when" means: Are you asking for a condition which is sufficient or for a condition which is both necessary and sufficient or for a condition which is just necessary?